# Loading an input value from another page using JQUERY load function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please guys is there a way i can make a value of the submit button to be loaded automatically from another page using the jquery `.load` function:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="(JQUERY LOADED PAGE VALUE HERE)" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#submit').load('page.php')
            }, 500);
        });
<script>
```

Comment: What is the result from `page.php`?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to a .get() and use the call back

```
$.get('page.php', function(data) { $('#submit').val(data); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use normal ajax for this. `.load()` is supposed to load HTML content.

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="(JQUERY LOADED PAGE VALUE HERE)" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'page.php',
                    success : function(data){
                        $('#submit').val($.trim(data));
                    }
                });
            }, 500);
        });
<script>
```